# my animation button don't appear long enough

Tags: java, android, xml, button

In my android app, I have 4 image buttons that are animated with an xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/home1"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/home1"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/home" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/home2"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

When I click on the button, the animation runs but it does not appear properly because the new activity opens so quickly. I want the full animation to be seen, I think i have do do a sleep method
but i didn't know wher exactly 
this is my action button :

```
   btn_photos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Launching News Feed Screen
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PhotosActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

pls any help :)

Comment: That xml is not the animation xml, its a state drawable xml.. check

Answer (score 0):

add this code

```
btn_photos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Launching News Feed Screen
        try{
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch( InterruptedException e) {}
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PhotosActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Tweak the delay at your desire. =]

Comment: so this forum there are trolls too, trying to steal good answers from others, reported

Answer (score 0):

Create a Runnable and start it inside your onClickListener. Give runnable a sleep time.

```
Runnable viewPhotos = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PhotosActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
};

btn_photos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Launching News Feed Screen
        Thread thread =  new Thread(null, viewPhotos, "ViewPhotos");
        thread.start();
    }
});
```